# With the API Manager product, can multiple users administer a single API?

Tags: wso2

With the API Manager product, can multiple users administer a single API? Is there any way in the API Publisher for one user to transfer ownership of an API to another user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using APIM 1.3.1 or previous releases, all the APIs are visible to all publishers. So, others who have publisher permission also can edit the API

Comment: Oh ok, I didn't initially realize that. Is there a way to restrict who can edit a particular API?

Comment: that feature will be available in the upcoming release, which we plan to release in May.